# How to post objects in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've got this viewmodel class with an integer Id and an object type.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int MyId { get; set; }

    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

MyObject Model is:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    [Key]
    public int ObjId { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

This controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MyId, MyObject.Number, MyObject.Name")]MyViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
//do something!
}
```

The view is:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyId , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("MyId", null, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyObject.Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyObject.Number, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "1", max = "3", step = "1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyObject.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyObject.Name , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyObject.Name , new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "1", max = "3", step = "1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyObject.Name , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" formaction="@Url.Action("Create")" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When I post data to controller, it recognize the MyId value but don't fill MyObject parameter. Any suggests to how to post an object with ViewModel?

Comment: Show the full view so we can see how you're trying to post the data.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: I have updated the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `@model MyViewModel` at the top of the view, there's no need to complicate it.

Make your submit on the view

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

and change the signature of the post method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
//do something!
}
```

The view model should then be bound.

Comment: Also might want to update the BeginForm to be safe to something like                 using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { class = "anyClassIfNeeded" }))
                { }

Comment: Thanks Barry: it works.
Yes on the top there is @model MyProject.Models.MyViewModel.
I've got a question, for a better comprehension: I'm using Entity Framework and by default is uses the method "Bind(Include)" to create the binding. But here this method doesn't work. 
Is it because ViewModel isn't used in EF ?

Comment: No it's more to do with the fact that `MyObject` is a nested object in the view model. The signature `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MyId, MyObject")]MyViewModel vm)` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MyId,MyObject, MyObject.Number, MyObject.Name")]MyViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You aren't including `MyObject` in `Bind(include)`